# Not Downloading Jars from Release version

Tags: java, maven, repository

My nexus repository are defined as following

1. maven-release - which contains my customer jars
2. maven-snapshots - which contains my project jars

and my settings xml file as bellows:

```
             <repository>
                    <id>nexus</id>
                    <name>nexus-repo-snapshots</name>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                        <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                    <url>https://nx0.my.biz/repository/maven-snapshots</url>
                    <layout>default</layout>
                </repository> 
                <repository>
                    <id>nexus</id>
                    <name>nexus-repo-release</name>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <url>https://nx0.my.biz/repository/maven-releases</url>
                    <layout>default</layout>
                </repository>
```

and my distributed management is as bellows:

```
    <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <name>Releases</name>
        <url>${nexus.url}/repository/maven-releases</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <name>Snapshot</name>
        <url>${nexus.url}/repository/maven-snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

I have uploaded my custom jars in maven releases

now what is happening that It is downloading jars from maven-snapshots only like

`Downloading from nexus: https://nx0.my.biz/repository/maven-snapshots/com/my/custom/2.4.0/custom-2.4.0.jar`

and giving error while building that 
Could not find artifact com.my:custom:jar:2.4.0 in nexus (https://nx0.my.biz/repository/maven-snapshots)

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

check your maven settings.xml.
if you set two mirror and both of them `mirrorOf` attribute been set to *,then maven will use the first mirror to download all the dependencies.
that almost killed my whole day.

Answer (score 0):

The [distributionManagement](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management) section of your pom is only used for uploading artifacts with either the deploy goal to the snapshot repository or the [maven release plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) to the release repository.

The [repositories](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories) section of your settings.xml will be used to download artifacts to your local repository (usually ~/.m2).

The repositories will be looked at in the order they are given in the settings.xml.

Comment: I just wanted to know if it does not find in maven-snapshots then It wont look for maven-releases..because It is happening in my case. Its seeing only in maven-snapshots which is last one